# Modify foreign key in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have this original migration that have already been run and sent upstream:

```
create table(:videos) do
  add :url, :string
  add :title, :string
  add :description, :text
  add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing)

  timestamps
end
create index(:videos, [:user_id])
```

Now i wish to change the foreign key on `user_id` to cascade deletions, so that when a user is deleted all of his associated videos will also be deleted.

I have tried the following migration:

```
alter table(:videos) do
  modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
end
```

But this raises an error:

```
(Postgrex.Error) ERROR (duplicate_object): constraint "videos_user_id_fkey" for relation "videos" already exists
```

How can I formulate a migration script that will change this foreign key according to my requirement?

---

**UPDATE**

I ended up with the following solution:

```
def up do
  execute "ALTER TABLE videos DROP CONSTRAINT videos_user_id_fkey"
  alter table(:videos) do
    modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
  end
end

def down do
  execute "ALTER TABLE videos DROP CONSTRAINT videos_user_id_fkey"
  alter table(:videos) do
    modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing)
  end
end
```

this drops the constraint before ecto tries to recreate it.

Comment: You have working answer in you question, it'be useful to post it as a separate answer so anyone can vote.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can drop the index before calling `alter`:

```
drop_if_exists index(:videos, [:user_id])
alter table(:videos) do
  modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
end
```

Doing the opposite is a little trickier:

```
execute "ALTER TABLE videos DROP CONSTRAINT videos_user_id_fkey"
create_if_not_exists index(:videos, [:user_id])
```

Comment: I ended up doing a variation of this.

Comment: The `drop_if_exists index(:videos, [:user_id])` line doesn't make sense since that removes a normal index, not a foreign key constraint. The answer by Jessie is better IMO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43572806/175830

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. The solution below by Max Clarke works.

Answer (score 43):

I'm not sure when this was added to Ecto, but at least in 2.1.6 there's no need for raw SQL anymore. `drop/1` now [supports constraints](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#drop/1) (`drop_if_exists/1` doesn't though):

```
def up do
  drop constraint(:videos, "videos_user_id_fkey")
  alter table(:videos) do
    modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
  end
end

def down do
  drop constraint(:videos, "videos_user_id_fkey")
  alter table(:videos) do
    modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing)
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn't support it with mysql as of now - `(ArgumentError) MySQL adapter does not support constraints`

Answer (score 8):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
def up do
  execute "ALTER TABLE videos DROP CONSTRAINT videos_user_id_fkey"
  alter table(:videos) do
    modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
  end
end

def down do
  execute "ALTER TABLE videos DROP CONSTRAINT videos_user_id_fkey"
  alter table(:videos) do
    modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :nothing)
  end
end
```

this drops the constraint before ecto tries to recreate it

Copied from the question.

Comment: This should be higher

Comment: Shouldn't `flush()` be used ?

`drop constraint(: videos, "videos_user_id_fkey")` should work.

Answer (score 8):

In [Ecto SQL 3.4.3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#modify/3):

"If the `:from` value is a `%Reference{}`, the adapter will try to drop the corresponding foreign key constraints before modifying the type."

```
modify :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all), from: references(:users)
```

Should work.  In working on a rollback, I worked out that this worked to clear the FK and remove the column:

```
remove :user_id, references(:users)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it can achieved with `alter table`. For example according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330517/912225) Postgres doesn't allow modifying constraints in `ALTER TABLE` statement. [MySQL also doesn't allow modifying constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381227/912225).

The easiest thing to do would be removing the field and adding it back if you don't have any data. Otherwise, you need use raw SQL with [`execute`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#execute/1)

Comment: I was hoping that there was a better way of doing it. In this particular example i could just drop the column and re-add it, but if this was a real-world situation that column would probably already contain valuable information that I would be very sorry to loose :)

Answer (score 2):

`from` option was introduced in [Ecto 3.0](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/3.0.0/Ecto.Migration.html#modify/3), so you can setup your migration in more elegant way:

```
defmodule App.Migrations.ChangeVideosUserConstraint do
  use Ecto.Migration
  def change do
    alter table(:videos) do
      modify(:user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all), from: references(:users))
    end
  end
end
```